# Filling table fields with value from textbox in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to fill table fields in Access 2013 with a value from a Combobox that is located on a form.
But i'm not receiving any errors and nothing happens when the code is executed.
I don't have the exact code i'm using but here is something very similar i found from a website:

```
   Dim d As Database
   Dim r As Recordset
   Dim Price, Qty, Total As Field
   Set d = CurrentDB()
   Set r = d.OpenRecordset("Table")
   Set Price= r.Fields("Price")
   Set Qty= r.Fields("Quantity")
   Set Total= r.Fields("Total")
   While Not r.EOF
      r.Edit
      Total=Price*Qty
      r.Update
      r.MoveNext
   Wend
   r.Close
```

I didn't use while not loop in my code but the rest of it is pretty similar.
After searching i thought adding MS DAO as reference would help but nothing changed.
My problem is that nothing happens when i execute the code, i even tried to remove the loop and make it only change a value but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Part of this problem is in

```
Dim Price, Qty, Total As Field
```

In VBA, that statement evaluates to :

```
Dim Price As Variant, Qty As Variant, Total As Field
```

which is probably not what you want to do. You need to specify an As Type after each declaration. Better yet, put each declaration on its own line.

You don't need any of those field variables -- just change your loop to:

```
While Not r.EOF
  r.Edit
  r!Total = r!Price * r!Qty
  r.Update
  r.MoveNext
Wend
```